# ImageMagick Installation in Docker container with External fonts for MoviePy

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

How to install ImageMagick in a docker container and also install external fonts for usage in MoviePy.

Answer (score 1):

The below Dockerfile contains two parts:

1. Installation of ImageMagick.
2. Installation of fonts and making MoviePy recognize them.

I'm using fonts from GoogleFonts, however, you can download fonts from any other website as well, you just need to have the `.ttf` files of the font inside the font folder of the container which is mentioned in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential xvfb xdg-utils wget ffmpeg libpq-dev vim libmagick++-dev fonts-liberation sox bc --no-install-recommends\
    && apt-get clean

## ImageMagicK Installation ##
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/distr && \
    cd /tmp/distr && \
    wget https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/releases/ImageMagick-7.0.11-2.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf ImageMagick-7.0.11-2.tar.xz && \
    cd ImageMagick-7.0.11-2 && \
    ./configure --enable-shared=yes --disable-static --without-perl && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
    cd /tmp && \
    rm -rf distr

## Installing External Fonts ##
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom \
    && for fontname in \
    'Mrs Saint Delafield' 'Arimo' 'Dosis'; \
    do \
    modified_fontname=$fontname//[ ]/_}; \
    wget "https://fonts.google.com/download?family=$fontname" -O $modified_fontname.zip; \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom; \
    unzip $modified_fontname.zip -d /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom; \
    rm $modified_fontname.zip; \
    done

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "-u", "main.py"]
```